# В чём ошибка при создании своей npx библиотеки

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Мне потребовалось создать свою npx библиотеку. Всё работает хорошо... Но только с заранее установленным пакетом:

```sh
npm i -g pkg
npx pkg some args
```

Если же просто ввести `npx pkg some args`, в духе `npx create-react-app`, то просит установить пакет, а потом выбрасывает ошибку:

```
"pkg" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

<sub>`lib/index.js`</sub>

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log(process.argv.slice(2).join(' ')); // упрощено до предела, т.к. сам код рабочий
```

<sub>`package.json`</sub>

```
{
  // name, version, description, keywords и проч. сгенерированы анкеткой
  "main": "lib/index.js"
  "bin": {
    "pkg": "lib/index.js" // сюда можно хоть `abrakadabra` вставить: всё равно не работает
  },
  "scripts": {
    // build скрипты
    "prepare": "del /q lib && npm run build",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "node lib/index"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Я смотрел на др. репозитории, как сам `create-react-app` и `cowsay`, но не нашёл каких-либо кардинальных отличий.

Собственно, вопрос: как исправить это недоразумение

---

Я пишу на Windows, `#!usr/bin/env` выглядит как какая-то юниксовская тема, может в этом дело?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123446/discussion-on-question-by-return-------npx-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это о-очень интересная ошибка: нужно было просто почистить кэш.

Полазив в source коде npx я понял, что кэш в приоритете и не важно, обновилась версия или нет. Я зашёл в свой кэш (чтобы узнать кэш выполните `npm config get cache` (об этом я тоже узнал из source кода)) и там были папки с именами PID в hex моих процессов, которыми я устанавливал пакеты (понятно, откуда я об этом узнал). Там были и `create-react-app`, и `cowsay`, и мой `pkg`, в котором я в файле `package.json` **не** указал `bin`, из-за чего соответствующая папка не появилась, из-за чего `cmd.exe` не может найти executable, из-за чего он и выбрасывает мне эту странную ошибку. Почистив кэш, я вынудил npx установить пакет заново — теперь-то оно работает.

Более коротко. В старой версии `pkg` я не указал `bin`, таким он сохранился в кэш и не хотел оттуда вылазить даже при обновлении версии, а кэш у npx в приоритете. Пришлось его оттуда выгонять силой (с помощью <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>).

И не надо ничего менять в `package.json`, не надо никаких ярлыков, никаких самодобавлений в `dependencies`, нужно было просто почистить кэш. А то, что он не обновляется, я считаю явным багом. Я бы написал issue, да репозиторий архивирован.

Comment: А кто-то вчера доказывал, что `create-react-app` не установлен и все работает так. Как же он, и все остальное, в кеш попало? И для обновления можно попробовать `npm i pkg --force`.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg я его не устанавливал. он впервые установился после `npx create-react-app`, и сейчас после очистки кэша он устанавливается в кэш после `npx create-react-app`, и мой `pkg` устанавливается в кэш после удаления, так что всё я правильно сделал, и всё я доказал

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg кэш — это отдельная папка, это не глобальное хранилище, не `node_modules` (куда установит пакет ваша команда), это отдельная папка, путь к которой лежит в конфиге npm. у npx свой отдельный кэш — `<cache>/_npx`, которым управляет npx. там у меня лежали (я их удалил для форсированного обновления) *только* пакеты, установленные мой через `npx`. всё правильно работает, просто у npx есть баг, из-за которого npx не следит за жизненным циклом кэшированных пакетов